# How to determine the value in effect

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Is there a JS way to determine the value in effect for an attribute of an element?

It is well understood that there is a precedence from referenced CSS files in order of declaration through embedded CSS and values defined in the style attribute of an element, with the most recent/most local taking effect.

Browser element inspection tools make it possible to determine the value in effect for an element styling attribute like (for example) `background-color`.

Is there a way to discover the value in effect programmatically?

I have used a canvas and js to creates what amounts to image maps with hover and click visual feedback, and I would love to make this respond to CSS styling on the canvas.

For example, if the canvas color is set to red then red should be the base color for hover highlights and selection marking.

At the moment this is all done by changing the values of "constants", but responding to CSS would be... elegant.

Comment: There's [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) but canvas "colors" are pixels you draw on in programmatically, that's not style

Comment: What do you mean by "canvas color"? If you mean background-color then you can read that using Amit's suggestion: `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: @Amit - write that up as an answer, it's *exactly* what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the current effective style by using [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). It returns an exotic array-like object that has all active style properties as well as some helper functions. To use:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el1');
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(el);
document.getElementById('style').innerHTML = computedStyle.cssText;
```

```css
#el1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
div:first-of-type {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="el1"></div>
<hr>
<div id="style"></div>
```